# Is $13x^5 + (3 − i)x^3 + (8 − i)(x^2 − x) + 1 − 2i$ irreducible in $(\mathbb{Q}[i])[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Is $$13x^5 + (3 − i)x^3 + (8 − i)(x^2 − x) + 1 − 2i$$ irreducible in $(\mathbb{Q}[i])[x]$?

I've tried using Eisenstein’s irreducibility criterion to prove that it is, but I don't think it applies here. Would anyone be able to tell me how to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Gaussian integers are a UFD, the Eisenstein criterion carries over. Try it on your polynomial with the Gaussian prime factor $2+i$.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure out what the factor would be. Would you mind telling me how you found that it's 2+i?

Comment: Multiply the coefficients by their complex conjugates. Except the leading one you get multiples of $5=2^2+1^2$, suggesting a factor of $2\pm i$.

Comment: @Dawid I was going to phrase the thought as :  Look at the norms of the coefficients to motivate the choice of a possible prime.